# Testing aasm state transitions with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, state-machine, aasm

I'm using aasm gem to handle state transitions in my project. I have a simple model that looks like this:

```
class TransferPostingBid < ActiveRecord::Base
  include AASM

  aasm :status do
    state :offered, initial: true
    state :wait_for_pap_confirmation
    state :confirmed_by_pap
    state :retracted_by_pap

    event :pap_choosed do
      transitions from: :offered, to: :wait_for_pap_confirmation
    end

    event :confirmed_by_pap do
      transitions from: :wait_for_pap_confirmation, to: :confirmed_by_pap
    end

    event :retracted_by_pap do
      transitions from: :wait_for_pap_confirmation, to: :retracted_by_pap
    end
  end
end
```

And I'm trying to test transitions with aasm built in rspec matchers:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe TransferPostingBid, type: :model do
  describe 'state transitions' do
    let(:transfer_posting_bid) { TransferPostingBid.new }

    it 'has default state' do
      expect(transfer_posting_bid).to transition_from(:offered).to(:wait_for_pap_confirmation).on_event(:pap_choosed)
    end
  end
end
```

When I run this spec it returns me following error:

```
 AASM::UnknownStateMachineError:
   There is no state machine with the name 'default' defined in TransferPostingBid!
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7):

You can try using the the `#on` method to specify which state machine you're testing:

```
transition_from(:offered).to(:wait_for_pap_confirmation).on_event(:pap_choosed).on(:status)
```